# iOS app run on selected devices

Tags: ios, titanium, device

I have created an iOS app and I want my app to run only on selected iOS devices such as iPad 3 and 4 and also iPhone 3,4,4S and 5.

How can I specify that in Titanium ?

Comment: There's no such thing as an iPhone 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your tiapp.xml to set a minimum version for iOS and minimum device processor.
Something like this:

```
<ios>
    <min-ios-ver>4.3</min-ios-ver>
    <plist>
        <dict>
            <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
            <array>
                <string>armv7</string>
                <string>armv7s</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </plist>
</ios>
```

And here is the list of devices that use each processor

```
ARMv6  = iPhone 2G/3G, iPod 1G/2G
ARMv7  = iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPod 3G/4G/5G, iPad, iPad 2, iPad 3, iPad Mini  
ARMv7s = iPhone 5, iPad 4
```

Comment: But over here if I add ARMv7 then that also includes iPad 1 and iPad 2 which should not be included

Comment: You could increase the min-ios-ver to 6.0, what would exclude also the iPad 1, but I don't believe there is any other way to exclude a specific device